# SO showed me a job ad for the company I work for

Tags: bug, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

Just noticed that Stack Overflow displayed an job ad to me, in the right sidebar, for the company I work for. I am even listed as an employee of the company (my profile appears in the "Who you'll work with" section).

Comment: Is it your job? Are you worried yet? ;)

Comment: This is hardly a *bug*. Sounds like an edge case that's not really worth creating a special case for

Comment: @TZHX very worried!

Comment: @Pekka웃 well, I'm assuming that SO tries to show relevant job posts to users. Since I already work at the company, its not relevant. Could be that a filter isn't configured correctly somewhere.

Comment: Would it be a promotion if you got it? Why would they not show it to you?

Comment: If they implemented this, there'd likely be worried enquiries from people who posted job offers because theirs isn't visible to them in the sidebar. Probably not worth changing

Comment: @Paulie_D fair point, though unlikely considering the size of the company (under 20, though listed as under 10 on SO).

Comment: Edit the name etc. to that of your boss.  Print off a paper copy and post it on the notice-board.

Comment: I reported this nearly six months ago, it is not a bug.

Comment: SO also sent me an email too,
I have the company name on my developer story. as @tzhx said, I'm starting to worry about my position :(

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Thanks for getting in touch!

Arguably in this instance we've actually done a rather good job of matching you with an employer. After all, you clearly *are* a good fit for this company, because you work there right now!

Of course, there's the more philosophical question of whether we should show you jobs at your current company at all. I think *yes* - at a larger company there may be opportunities in different roles that you'd be interested in. (Supposing for example that you worked on the Kindle team at Amazon - you may be interested in positions available on the S3 team.)

Perhaps we could mitigate it by being smart about the size of your company, or with a setting which allows you to hide jobs at your current employer, but those both seem like complicated solutions to a problem which isn't so bad in the first place. (On the other hand, as @TZHX points out, there's the unlikely-but-alarming scenario in which you see your own job being advertised!)

Moreover, both of those ideas suffer from the problem that you could be browsing the site anonymously. If we don't know who you are, then we can't hide your employer from you.

This is the sort of thing we like to argue about, though, so perhaps one of my colleagues will show up here and disagree with me.

We do perform that filtering at the other end, though. Your current employer won't be able to see your profile in the database. No one wants their boss to find out that they're looking for a new job.

Comment: have you considered giving user an option to decide whether they want to see job ads of their current company or not

Comment: Consider turning it around so that the employer has a switch to hide posting from employees.

Comment: @Kevin How would that be achieved? Employees may be logged out, or not linked in any way with their employer in SO.

Comment: What makes you think it is a good fit? The OP is looking for a new job and the employer is looking to hire someone else with the same qualifications. The human factor matters quite a lot.

Comment: @TZHX I can't imagine OP was surprised to see their current employer advertised while they were anonymised.

Comment: @Aswan You seem to have missed the point of my comment here. Read it in context, with the comment I was responding to, and try again.

Comment: @TZHX you're right, my mistake.

Comment: A year ago, for a few months, SO displayed a job ad in my side bar: my recently vacated position, at the company I resigned from. It was for a C#/Xamarin position. I'm an iOS developer coerced into C#/Xamarin, which is why I left the company. So wrong on so many levels, LOL.

Comment: @TZHX Yeah, I realize that would only work if the employee was signed in and had an up-to-date, authentic profile.

Comment: The ability to dismiss recommendations would resolve this... and would be a nice feature in general.

Comment: "Your current employer won't be able to see your profile in the database. No one wants their boss to find out that they're looking for a new job." Thank you for doing this!

Answer (score 8):

It's possible that this is a bug, but I don't think it is.

If you're a "QA tester", for example, you might be interested in a job as a "C++ developer". If the job is at the company you already work for, it would be beneficial to consider applying for the position because the company already knows you.

Answer (score 3):

You can now hide employers (I don't think this was a possibility when this question was first posted). If you click through the employer page by clicking on the employer's name in the job posting, and click the menu button in the top-right corner you can dismiss it:

[image]

This is a bit non-obvious, IMHO, as it's not clear that you can click on the company name (as it's just regular black text).

You can also dismiss it with individual job postings, by the way, either by using the menu on the job page or clicking the "x" in the jobs listing.