# StackExchange App recommends a job I already have

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, android-app

The Stack Exchange App is recommending me [a job I already have](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/125462/software-developer-java-developersnl) and it should know this because I'm associated with the organization it is recommending. The page lists me under "Who you’ll work with".

[[image: The recommendation]

Wasn't sure if I should post this here or the Stack Exchange meta as the question pertains to both the Stack Exchange App and Stack Overflow Jobs.

Comment: Well, you have to give them credit for accurate matching...

Comment: Not sure if this is the android or iOS app, so i took a guess. Feel free to retag as necessary

Comment: Related (about an ad on the main site): [SO showed me a job ad for the company I work for](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321628/so-showed-me-a-job-ad-for-the-company-i-work-for)

Comment: Just because you are associated with the company doesn't mean you would not be interested in another job at the same company.  Especially if it a better fit or pays better than your current job ;-)